# Wicket > v1.5: Acces file from CSSResourceReference

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket

today I was damaging my brain for too long on how I am able in Apache wicket to access the actual filecontent of a CssResourceReference?

The CSSResourceReference is declared like that:

```
private final CssResourceReference CSS_GLOBAL = new CssResourceReference(BasePage.class, "css/global.css");
```

...and is meant to be used for basic header contribution as well as it's contents need to be accessible from within a behaviour for feeding a LessCSSEngine.

I know that I am able to get the url (via the [WicketWiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/getting-a-url-for-display.html)):

```
RequestCycle.get().urlFor(CSS_GLOBAL, null);
```

But from there on, I am stuck on how to actually access the file and contents.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the content that easily because a ResourceReference in Wicket is meant to load by a Request. You can simulate a Request and read the response but this is too much work.
Anyways you don't need Wicket to access files in your class path:

```
final InputStream stream = BasePage.class.getResourceAsStream("css/global.css");
final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
```